# How to generate pdf with WinEDT

Tags: errors, miktex, winedt

I am new to LaTeX and look for a starting point.

I downloaded WinEDT, and loaded a sample demo file; Then I configured `Options` > `Execution Modes` and set it to MiKTeX installation (However I am not sure which directory I should select `pdftex`, `tex`, `miktex`....), following are what I used:

```
Tex Root: D:\Program Files\MiKTeX
Tex bin: D:\Program Files\MiKTeX\miktex\bin
Dvi Viewer: D:\Program Files\MiKTeX\miktex\bin\yap.exe
```

But after `texify` it, can't see any output

This is what I get on console

```
Command Line:   texify.exe --src --tex-option=--interaction=errorstopmode --tex-option=--synctex=-1 "C:\Users\TA\AppData\Roaming\WinEdt Team\WinEdt 9\Samples\Examples\Demo.tex"
Startup Folder: C:\Users\TA\AppData\Roaming\WinEdt Team\WinEdt 9\Samples\Examples

latex: try `latex --help' for more information.
latex: unrecognized option `--synctex=-1'
texify: latex exited with bad status, quitting.
texify: see "Demo.log" for errors.


_____________________________________________________________________

 TeXify Compilation Report (Pages: 0)

 Errors: 0   Warnings: 0   Bad Boxes: 0
___________________________________________
```

---

Comment: Don't start with texify. Try out pdflatex alone first.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer You mean instead of texify? I tried pdflatex and all of the others, I receive no error but no file is generated too

Comment: Check the log file. And create your own minimal hello world example.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Ooops! very user unfriendly it is! I didn't find any "demo.log" on my entire computer, as you notice the error message, it doesn't give the path! where can I find log files?

Comment: The error message tells you that the startup folder was `C:\Users\TA\AppData\Roaming\WinEdt Team\WinEdt 9\Samples\Examples`. So look for log-files there. And one reason for my advice to create your own example is that you then know where it is ;-).

Answer (score 4):

As you can see from the message captured by WinEdt from texify error stream, it clearly says:

```
latex: unrecognized option `--synctex=-1'
```

This means that the version of latex.exe you have installed doesn't support synctex.

In other words, you have a very old TeX distribution installed (MiKTeX in your case) and you should upgrade.

If you can't, you can simply inform WinEdt that you don't want to pass the command line options `--synctex=-1` to your compiler.

To do that, go to Options -> Execution Modes -> PDF Viewer tab and deselect the option "Use --synctex switch when --src is enabled".

[image]